# amcharts4 not shown single tooltip for each series when user mouse over, how can i do this?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

***I have a series chart in amcharts4 but I'm tired to find an argument in amcharts4 to showing the single tooltip in amcharts4 when user mouse over on series***
which argument can set to shown mouse over series for each series?

my chart setting is :

```
<script>    
am4core.ready(function() {

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("test1div", am4charts.XYChart);

// Increase contrast by taking evey second color
chart.colors.step = 2;

// Set up data source
chart.dataSource.url ="/static/json/DATA.json";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "i";    

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("hour", "YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm");
dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm";

var valueAxis1 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

function createAxisAndSeries(field, name) {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series.dataFields.valueY = field;
        series.dataFields.dateX = "DATETIME";
        series.strokeWidth = 2;
        series.yAxis = valueAxis1;
        series.name = name;
        series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
        series.tensionX = 0.9;
        series.tensionY = 0.9;
    valueAxis1.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis1.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
    valueAxis1.renderer.grid.template.disabled = false;
    valueAxis1.cursorTooltipEnabled = true;
    valueAxis1.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueAxis1.getFillFromObject = false;
}

createAxisAndSeries{"testseries1","testseries1"};
createAxisAndSeries{"testseries2","testseries2"};

   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "hover over series" do you mean hovering over a line? Your series does not have any bullets or such.

Comment: Yes mouse over line series

Comment: That's bad UX, since lines are thing and therefore hard to hover on. Perhaps you want to add bullets? Those are larger and therefore easier to hover/tap on?

Comment: In previews version easy i do that with one argument to bullet series. There'snt any argument . I want just single tooltip ballon with hover over searies for each of them shown